# PHP code not being executed (commented out) while using slim framework

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am using slim framework (routing etc) and illuminate database to output data on my webpage but it does not seem to be working as the php code keeps getting commented out when i load the webpage in browser (chrome).

my routing (I am using slim-twig as well):

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'index.php');
});
```

php code I am trying to render in index.php

```
<?php

    require "/vendor/autoload.php";

    $tournaments = Tournaments::all();

    phpinfo();

    foreach ($tournaments as $tournament) {
        echo $tournament->name;
    }

?>
```

^ this code comes out as `<!-- code -->` in browser code view.

I am new to php frameworks so explanation would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "View" layer is not responsible to fetch the data. Instead you should pass all the data to view with the 3. parameter.

```php
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    $viewData = [
        'tournaments' => Tournaments::all(),
    ];

    return $this->get('view')->render($response, 'index.twig', $viewData);
});
```

index.twig

```
{% for tournament in tournaments %}
    {{ tournament.name}}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using that I am getting "Argument 3 passed to Slim\Views\Twig::render() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\routes.php on line 20" error.

and using even a simple <?php echo "test"; ?> doesnt seem to work as it gets commented out anyways. Does it has to do anything with the rendering inside routing?